# What is the definition of $e^{ix}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

This might seem silly, but in proving Euler Formula taught in Calculus classes, we make the assumption that

$\frac{d}{dx}e^{ix} = ie^{ix}$

However $e^{g}$ Pre-Euler’s Formula, only takes in real numbers for g.  If we tried to use the Chain Rule where $g = ix$ we have no definition for that.

My question is, how do we know, Pre-Euler’s Formula, that $e^{z}$ exists for complex values of z, and how do we know that $e^{ix}$ is differentiable at $ix$.  Basically what is the definition of $e^{ix}$ before knowing Euler's Formula.

Comment: The function $f$ who differentiate only "takes" real numbers (it "spits" complex numbers *out*). $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is defined as $f(x) = e^{ix}$, so you differentiate it with respect to the *real* variable $x$.

Comment: $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} e^{kx}=ke^{kx}$ where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: @ClementC. The OP is asking for a definition of $e^{z}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @MarkViola I was reacting to "If we tried to use the Chain Rule [...]" and "differentiable at $ix$" (instead of "at $x$, which is what is used). To be frank, I don't understand the last part: surely, the textbook must have **defined** $e^{ix}$, otherwise, the whole premise of the question is strange (you don't prove things about quantities not even defined yet).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I agree; the function must have been defined in the OP's text book.

Answer (score 5):

A natural way to define $e^z$ for any complex $z$ is by the Taylor expansion $$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
When $z$ is purely imaginary then this yields Euler's Formula as
$$e^{ix} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}+i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
=\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

Comment: Another way to define $e^z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is given by $$e^z=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n$$ just as in the limit definition of $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

When I was teaching, I always used the series definition, as explained in @ErikParkinson’s answer. But you may also define
$$
e^z=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n\,.
$$
When you look at this closely, the formula $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ becomes very reasonable.